# How can I redirect the stdout to a temporary file and open it with vim or something?

Tags: bash, shell

I don't know if this can be done with one line bash command? How about a script? Please explain what is the script doing. And hope that, when I quit the vim, this temporary file will be deleted automatically :)

Comment: look at [tee](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tee_(command))

Comment: No scripting at all, just run the following command `some-command | vi -`. Usually `vi` or `vim` refers each other (via symlinks or aliases). So you can use any of them in your work.

Comment: Why edit a file and then delete it?  Do you mean to use `view`?

Answer (score 1):

To redirect stdout to a file in Unix/Linux environment you just need to use `>` like below.

```
yourUnixCommand > output.txt

vim output.txt
```

But once you exit from output.txt it will not automatically delete the file. You have to delete the file manually like below:-

```
 rm output.txt
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean you are inside `vi` and you want to insert the output of a command into the editor at the current position, try:

```
:r ! date
```

and it will insert the output of the `date` command into your file.